# How may I fix NLTK Chunking Error?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, nltk

I was trying to train my own NLTK chunker using the tutorial http://streamhacker.com/2008/12/29/how-to-train-a-nltk-chunker/

I wrote the code as,

```
>>> import nltk
>>> import nltk.chunk
>>> def conll_tag_chunks(chunk_sents):
    tag_sents = [nltk.chunk.tree2conlltags(tree) for tree in chunk_sents]
    return [[(t, c) for (w, t, c) in chunk_tags] for chunk_tags in tag_sents]

>>> import nltk.corpus, nltk.tag
>>> from nltk.metrics import accuracy
>>> def ubt_conll_chunk_accuracy(train_sents, test_sents):
    train_chunks = conll_tag_chunks(train_sents)
        test_chunks = conll_tag_chunks(test_sents)

        u_chunker = nltk.tag.UnigramTagger(train_chunks)
        print 'u:', accuracy(u_chunker, test_chunks)

        ub_chunker = nltk.tag.BigramTagger(train_chunks, backoff=u_chunker)
        print 'ub:', accuracy(ub_chunker, test_chunks)

        ubt_chunker = nltk.tag.TrigramTagger(train_chunks, backoff=ub_chunker)
        print 'ubt:', accuracy(ubt_chunker, test_chunks)

        ut_chunker = nltk.tag.TrigramTagger(train_chunks, backoff=u_chunker)
        print 'ut:', accuracy(ut_chunker, test_chunks)

        utb_chunker = nltk.tag.BigramTagger(train_chunks, backoff=ut_chunker)
        print 'utb:', accuracy(utb_chunker, test_chunks)


>>> conll_train = nltk.corpus.conll2000.chunked_sents('train.txt')
>>> conll_test = nltk.corpus.conll2000.chunked_sents('test.txt')
>>> ubt_conll_chunk_accuracy(conll_train, conll_test)
```

But here, I am getting the error as,

```
>>> ubt_conll_chunk_accuracy(conll_train, conll_test)
u:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    ubt_conll_chunk_accuracy(conll_train, conll_test)
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 6, in ubt_conll_chunk_accuracy
    print 'u:', accuracy(u_chunker, test_chunks)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\metrics\scores.py", line 38, in accuracy
    if len(reference) != len(test):
TypeError: object of type 'UnigramTagger' has no len()
>>> treebank_sents = nltk.corpus.treebank_chunk.chunked_sents()
>>> ubt_conll_chunk_accuracy(treebank_sents[:2000], treebank_sents[2000:])
u:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    ubt_conll_chunk_accuracy(treebank_sents[:2000], treebank_sents[2000:])
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 6, in ubt_conll_chunk_accuracy
    print 'u:', accuracy(u_chunker, test_chunks)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\metrics\scores.py", line 38, in accuracy
    if len(reference) != len(test):
TypeError: object of type 'UnigramTagger' has no len()
>>>
```

If anyone may kindly suggest, how may I fix this error? Thanks in advance. 
I am using NLTK 3.1,Python2.7.11 on MS-Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for the [accuracy](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/metrics/scores.html#accuracy) method of the [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.metrics.html) package

> ***nltk.metrics.scores.accuracy(reference, test)***
>
> reference values and a corresponding list of test values, return the
>   fraction of corresponding values that are equal. In particular, return
>   the fraction of indices 0
>
> **Parameters**:
>    - **reference** (list) – An ordered list of reference values.
>    - **test** (list) – A list of values to compare against the corresponding
>   reference values.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I found the package in metrics and tried to block if len(reference) != len(test) and the raise ValueError("Lists must have the same length.") but now getting a different error as,return float(sum(x == y for x, y in izip(reference, test))) / len(test)
TypeError: izip argument #1 must support iteration please suggest.

Comment: You shouldn't be changing the source code of the module. Why are you refusing to pass a list as expected?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I tried to change as >>> conll_train = list(nltk.corpus.conll2000.chunked_sents('train.txt'))
>>> conll_test = list(nltk.corpus.conll2000.chunked_sents('test.txt')) but not helping much. I found another module as >>> train_chunks=treebank_chunk.chunked_sents()[:3000]
>>> test_chunks=treebank_chunk.chunked_sents()[3000:]
>>> chunker=TagChunker(train_chunks)
>>> score=chunker.evaluate(test_chunks)
>>> score.accuracy()
0.9732039335251428 is going fine.

Comment: The code it's not very readable in a comment, so I'm unable to help any further. Try to post another question if you are stuck @SubhabrataBanerjee.

Comment: I am not stuck, Sir. I tried another example. That worked. Should I write my new code in pastebin? It seems you can not read it.